# Packaging Visual Workflow - can I install into professional edition?

Tags: managed-package, package, visual-workflow

I have created a simple visual workflow which is run by clicking a button on an Account. I understand that I can package up this component so it can be made available as part of a managed package. So far, so good...

Visual Workflows are shown as available in Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions. Does this mean that I can't package up a VW component and make it available to prof orgs? Is there any difference for ISV partners?

Comment: I have just created an unmanaged package with a simple flow included and cannot install into a professional edition org. 'Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: Flow Versions'

Answer (score -1):

Good question. I also work with a client who uses Professional Edition and was thinking of building a Flow for Lead lookup in a developer org; packaging it and installing it into a PE org.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.